CSRBB NIIS Modeling
I am seeking insight on how CSRBB NIIS for a Fixed Rate HQLA portfolio would be calculated? CSRBB EVE is understandable and IRRBB NIIS is also clear, however I am unable to make sense of how you would calculate CSRBB NIIS. Any thoughts would be appreciated - Many thanks in advance!
Abbreviations
CSRBB credit spread risk arising from non-trading book activities
EVE economic value of equity
HQLA high quality liquid assets
IRRBB interest rate risks for banking book
NII net interest income
